# Load remote form for editing in bootstrap modal using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, bootstrap-modal

This is what I am trying:

To open modal:

```
<a href="" class="label label-important" 
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editFee" 
data-id="'.$month['fid'].'" title="Edit '.$month['status'].' Fee">Edit</a>';
```

This is the `modal dialog`:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editFee" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
style="width: 25%" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
           <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                 <div class="modal-header">
                   <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Pay Fee</h4>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                    <!--Load remode editfee.php--!>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is `editfee.php`

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET['id'];
$fee = QueryFee('Feetable', $id);
foreach($fee as $feeForm):
?>
<form>
<input type="text" id="amount" value="<?php echo $feeForm['amount']; ?>">
<input type="text" id="dateFee" value="<?php echo $feeForm['dateFee']; ?>">
<input type="submit" id="submitFee" value="Save Fee">
</form>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

And finally the `jquery ajax`:

```
$(document).on("click", ".label", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id= $("#id").val();
        dataEdit = 'id='+id;
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            data:dataEdit,
            url:'editfee.php',
            success:function(data) {
              $(".modal-body").val(data);             
            }
          });

    });
```

I am using Bootstrap modal V2.0.4. The above code does open the dialog but without the remote data from editfee.php. Please help me.

Comment: use `$(".modal-body").html(data); ` instead of `$(".modal-body").val(data); `

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now it's working. But please can you post your answer with more detail explanation and suggestion for better integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, this code can't work:

```
var id= $("#id").val();
```

Your must to use something like this:

```
var id = $(this).data('id');
```

And finish by:

```
$(".modal-body").html(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".modal-body").val(data);
```

will not work, Because modal-body is just a div not an input element. So we should give

```
$(".modal-body").html(data);
```

instead of

```
$(".modal-body").val(data);
```

`.val()` attribute only for input elements. `.html()` is for appending html contents into the div.

And get the id attribute by

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

or

```
$(this).prop("id")
```